# Cassandra Java date issue

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a date as string and now I want to persist the same datetime in a timestamp column in Cassandra db. On cqlsh query the timestamp is shown as  different from the actual one.
I am parsing it using simple date formatter SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy") and storing.

ex: String date : Wed Jan 15 14:29:00 2020, 
In db: 2020-01-16 05:50:40.000000+0000

Also sometime, I am getting this error: DateOverFlowWarning: Some timestamps are larger than Python datetime can represent. Timestamps are displayed in milliseconds from epoch.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I do not use Cassandra. But perhaps this will help.

## Data types

As you seem to have learned, do not store date-time values as text when your database supports an appropriate date-time data type.

## Text formats

And, FYI, your format for representing a date-time value is terrible. When serializing date-time values as text, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

## Moment versus date-with-time-of-day

Another problem: You are trying to track moments with your use of type [`timestamp` in Cassandra](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html#timestamps), but your stored strings such as `Wed Jan 15 14:29:00 2020` is not a moment. Without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, we cannot know if that time of almost 2:30 PM is 2:30 PM in Tokyo Japan or 2:30 PM in Toledo Ohio US, two very different moments several hours apart.

If you know the intended time zone for that date and time-of-day, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. I will assume that UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds) was intended.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/rS6q9l).

## Database

If you have a driver for Cassandra that supports JDBC 4.2 and later, you should be able to submit this *java.time* object directly.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

If not, you can get a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 UTC.

```
long milliseconds = odt.toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;
```

> milliseconds: 1579098540000

Going the other direction.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( milliseconds ) ;
```

> getting this error: DateOverFlowWarning: Some timestamps are larger than Python datetime can represent

I can only guess. Somewhere in your toolchain is a Python library. I suppose that library is limited to using a 32-bit integer. But you need a 64-bit integer to represent the count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z for a Cassandra `timestamp` value.

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).